# Try and find the words

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, word-problem

Each line refers to one word - find them!
26. Who needs a best friend?  
26. all powerful.
50. Doctors lose business.
63. Judging books now, are we?
73. I point and squeak!
94. Clay-making magic!

Hint:

> 1. The puzzle is not coming from a crossword.
> 2. The words are not connected to each other. I.e. There are 6 separate puzzles...

Comment: This sounds like a crossword type puzzle, so are there lengths of words available?

Comment: ummm ... not really but sort of :-) :-)  (it's part of the puzzle- when you get it you'll know ;-)

Comment: are the numbers relevant? Can I be confident my 6 words are correct because of some relationship to the numbers?

Comment: @KateGregory yes exactly

Comment: I like the way one clue is fairly easy, two other clues help deduce the system, and the last clue is truly mysterious. I even tried "pygmalion"

Comment: @hmmn thanks! it's my very own homegrown concoction!

Comment: You shouldn't have six unconnected puzzles in one post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

​26. Who needs a best friend? 
​26. all powerful.

> `dog`  (or its reverse)

Almost there:

> ```
>              D    O   G
>              4 + 15 + 7  =  26. Who needs a best friend?.
>  
>              G    O   D
>              7 + 15 + 4  =  26. all powerful.
>  
>    A    P    P    L   E
>    1 + 16 + 16 + 12 + 5  =  50. Doctors lose business.
>  
>    C    O    V   E    R
>    3 + 15 + 22 + 5 + 18  =  63. Judging books now, are we?
>  
>    M    O    U    S   E
>   13 + 15 + 21 + 19 + 5  =  73. I point and squeak!
> ```

So close:

> ```
>   P    O    R   C   E    L   A    I    N
>  16 + 15 + 18 + 3 + 5 + 12 + 1 +  9 + 14  =  93. Clay-making magic!
>
>            C   A    S    S   I    U    S
>            3 + 1 + 19 + 19 + 9 + 21 + 19  =  91. Clay-making magic!
>
>            R    O    W    L   I    N   G
>           18 + 15 + 23 + 12 + 9 + 14 + 7  =  98. Clay-making magic!
> ```

Thank you, @IvanBarreto and @manshu!:

> ```
>     P    O    T    T   E    R
>    16 + 15 + 20 + 20 + 5 + 18   =  94. Clay-making magic!
> ```

Comment: Last one would've been thought of by a Potter.

Comment: Why didn't you used the word "Potter" in your edit?

Comment: Thanks, @manshu, It was one of the first words i tried but got the math wrong. Sheesh.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the rest, but the fifth line is

> mouse, referring to the compute mouse and the animal.

The others may be similar.

Comment: ok. good start! p.s. it's not coming from any crossword...

Answer (score 2):

A wild shot in the dark.

Are the 3rd and 4th:

> Under - as in: no more bills after the patient goes *under*.
>  Cover - as in: don't judge a book by it's *cover*.

In which case the first could be:

> Cat - since we have *undercover mouse*: a cat's toy.
>  We also have *find it* in the title...

Can't fit the rest so probably barking up the wrong tree.